# which is better in general, map or vector in c++?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector, dictionary

As I know that accessing an element in vector takes constant time while in map takes logarithmic time. However, storing a map takes less memory than storing a vector.

Therefore, I want to ask which one is better in general? I'm considering using one of those two in my program, which has about 1000 elements. I plan to use 3 dimensional vector, which would take 1000x1000x1000 elements.

Comment: Are you sure a map uses less space than a vector?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the container. See this flow chart: http://www.linuxsoftware.co.nz/containerchoice.png

Comment: Perhaps read a book on the standard library before posting any more questions like this?

Comment: Given your first paragraph, why are you asking the question!?  Neither is better in general; they are suited to different applications.  Also why ask "in general" and then give a specific application!?  The description of your application is too vague; but think about 1000x1000x1000 = 1,000,000,000; do you really want to use that many Gb for 1000 objects?!

Comment: What's Your platform or more exactly what's the address space for Your process on Your platform. There are systems, which are quite common, where 3 dimensional vector with 1000x1000x1000 elements in memory can be a "little problem".

Comment: Which is better in general, a hammer or a saw in carpentry?

Comment: @Fred Larson:  I don't know, but I'd swear that the people who wrote the code I'm trying to integrate now would use either interchangeably.

Comment: Your first and, for now, only concern should be reducing the number of elements stored at one time below a billion.

Comment: @Jonathan: Map uses less space than a vector if the 3D vector will be sparsely populated (i.e. mostly zeros). The map stores 3D coordinates as the key. It's a perfectly legitimate way of implementing sparse vectors/matrices (see Boost.uBlas).

Comment: @tsubasa: You should indicate in your question whether your 3D vector will be sparsely populated. Your question will make a lot more sense if it is indeed sparse.

Comment: To all the naysayers, please read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix

Answer (score 15):

There is no correct answer to this question. The correct question should be "which is better for the specific application --insert your project here--". To choose the correct container you need to explain how it will be used.

Comment: Amen, brother! It's all a matter of trade-offs (as is usually in life generally ;)

Answer (score 10):

A map is an associative container -- it serves a completely different function from a vector. Use a map if you want to associate keys with values. If your keys are just nonnegative consecutive integers, then a vector is superior in every way.

Answer (score 7):

Vector and Map are two different containers used for different purposes. IF there was one better, the other would NOT exist ...

Answer (score 5):

First of all, storing a map will almost definitely take more memory than a vector since a vector is simply a contiguous block and a map contains a tree structure.

The answer to your question of which is better is that it depends on the problem you are trying to solve.  It really comes down to how you want to be able to index your data.  If your data can be indexed linearly by an integer, then vector will perform the best.

However, there are many cases where you'll want to access your data in some other way.  For example, if you want to index your data using a string (like a dictionary lookup), then the map will perform better.  To index data with a string using a vector, you would have to perform a linear search (O(n)) to find an element if you don't keep the vector sorted.  A map would only have to perform a binary search (O(log n)) which would be a LOT faster as n grows.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as better in general. It all depends on the operations You are going to perform and on the frequency of those operations.

Vectors don't use more space than map, for the same number of elements. However such a thing, like a sparse matrix for example, sometimes may be implemented more efficiently using map.

Answer (score 2):

It is frankly rediculous to suggest that you creat 1,000,000,000, empty objects to store just 1000 useful ones.  If you think a vector will be faster, you are probably very wrong when you consider all the swapfile thrashing, dynamic memory allocation, and unnecessary object construction that will ensue!

The description of your application is probably too vague; but if a value can be indexed by x,y,z; then use an object containing x,y,z as the map key.  It will not take long to locate just 1000 objects - that is a very small map.

Answer (score 2):

If you have sparse 3-dimension array, you can save a lot of memory using map with the key as combination of indexes. For your case with indexes < 1000, key can be 32 bit unsigned integer:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
int index1 = 12, index2 = 34, index3 = 56;

// construct key:
uint32_t key = 
  ((index1&0x3FF) << 20) | 
  ((index2&0x3FF) << 10) | 
  (index3&0x3FF)
  );

// restore indexes:
index1 = (key >> 20) & 0x3FF;
index2 = (key >> 10) & 0x3FF;
index3 = (key) & 0x3FF;
```

Answer (score 1):

Deque is a more appropriate replacement for a vector than a map.  But it depends on your needs.   A vector requires linear memory for all its data, but a deque does not.  And a deque is can be used as a drop in replacement for a vector in most cases.

Comment: How is deque relevant here? Without data compression, and usually even with, there is no such thing as a structure that doesn't require linear memory for its data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a key-value component, use map. If you want a random-access-by-number solution, or an iteratively ordered solution, use vector.

Check your data structures/algorithm analysis text for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I consider `vector<>` to be the best default choice of container (except for `vector<bool>`).  If I have a reason to prefer another container, I use the other one; if not, I use `vector<>` (or `deque<bool>`).  That's as close as I can get to "better in general".

There are reasons for all the STL containers, things they do better than any other one.  Without knowing what you're going to be using the data structure for, I can't be any more help.

However, the penalties for using the wrong structure go up with the size.  If you have a few dozen elements, any class will do.  If you're talking about a billion elements, you really do want to get it right (and make sure your computer will handle it - you probably need a 64-bit app with a lot of RAM).

Answer (score 0):

If your 3D matrix will be sparsely populated (i.e. mostly zeros), then you'll be interested in [`boost::ublas::sparse_matrix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm). If I recall correctly, by default, it uses `std::map` as the underlying container. It provides operators for easy row/column  indexing (as well as row/column/element iterators).

EDIT: Nevermind, I thought boost::ublas had 3D matrices. It seems that it doesn't. It also seems that `sparse_matrix` has been replaced by new matrix types having sparse storage. It's been a long time since I used that library.

You can still look at Boost.uBlas for inspiration in rolling your own sparse 3D matrix.